# Is ANTLR available on QBasic?

Tags: antlr

I have just started studying about compiler design. And i have a little task to write a grammar on QBasic. But there are only few targeted languages on ANTLR. Is it possible on QBasic? Please anyone explain about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest repository of ANTLR grammars I know of in one place is at [this Github page](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4).  And it doesn't look like QBasic is among them.

I've written a grammar/interpreter or three with BASIC-like syntax with domain-specific extensions (and no line numbers!) but it doesn't look like anyone has undertaken QBasic in ANTLR4, not publicly at least.